# Average Multiple Fields Whilst Ignoring Blanks in Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to average multiple fields in each record in Access 2016. I want to be able to import the query into Excel for further analysis.

Some of the records contain blank fields which I want to ignore. I first tried using Nz which worked in Access but can't be imported into Excel.

I then tried the following:

```
SELECT Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTR, B365H, B365D, B365A, BWH, BWD, BWA, IWH, IWD, IWA, LBH, LBD, LBA, PSH, PSD, PSA, WHH, WHD, WHA, VCH, VCD, VCA, (iif(isnull(B365H))+ iif(isnull(BWH))+ iif(isnull(IWH))+ iif(isnull(LBH))+ iif(isnull(PSH))+ iif(isnull(WHH))+ iif(isnull(VCH)))/7 AS AvgHome
FROM [Bund]
GROUP BY Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTR, B365H, B365D, B365A, BWH, BWD, BWA, IWH, IWD, IWA, LBH, LBD, LBA, PSH, PSD, PSA, WHH, WHD, WHA, VCH, VCD, VCA;
```

But get a "Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression" error.

Can anyone see what the issue is?

Thanks

Comment: Your `IIF()` function argument are not provided for TRUE and FALSE condition.

Comment: What would be value if `isnull(B365H)` is true and what if flase?

Comment: Can use Nz() function. `Nz(WHH,0)`

Comment: Hi Haurn, if the field is blank it should not be included in the average calculation, if it contains a number (it will only ever contain a number or blank) it should use that number.

Comment: Hi June, I can't import the query into Excel because Excel doesn't recognise Nz.

Comment: What do you want the results to be?

Comment: Hi Gordon, I want to ignore the null values. So the query should average all fields with numbers, ignoring nulls. All fields are either a number or null. I can't use Nz because Excel doesn't recognise it when I try to import the data for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Is Not Null*:

```
Abs((B365H Is Not Null) + (BWH Is Not Null) + (IWH Is Not Null) + (LBH Is Not Null) + (PSH Is Not Null) + (WHH Is Not Null) + (VCH Is Not Null)) / 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
SELECT Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTR, B365H, B365D, B365A, BWH, BWD, BWA, IWH, IWD, IWA, LBH, LBD, LBA, PSH, PSD, PSA, WHH, WHD, WHA, VCH, VCD, VCA, (Nz(B365H,0)+ Nz(BWH,0)+ Nz(IWH,0)+ Nz(LBH,0)+ Nz(PSH,0)+ Nz(WHH,0)+ Nz(VCH,0))/7 AS AvgHome
FROM [Bund]
GROUP BY Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTR, B365H, B365D, B365A, BWH, BWD, BWA, IWH, IWD, IWA, LBH, LBD, LBA, PSH, PSD, PSA, WHH, WHD, WHA, VCH, VCD, VCA;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using aggregation functions, so `select distinct` is simpler.

Then, if you want to treat `NULL` values as `0`, you can use `nz()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTR, B365H, B365D, B365A, BWH, BWD, BWA,
       IWH, IWD, IWA, LBH, LBD, LBA, PSH, PSD, PSA, WHH, WHD, WHA, VCH, VCD, VCA,
       (nz(B365H, 0) + nz(BWH, 0) + nz(IWH, 0) + nz(LBH, 0) + nz(PSH, 0) + nz(WHH, 0) + nz(VCH, 0))/7 AS AvgHome
FROM [Bund];
```

If you want to *ignore* `NULL` values, then you need to handle the denominator as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTR, B365H, B365D, B365A, BWH, BWD, BWA,
       IWH, IWD, IWA, LBH, LBD, LBA, PSH, PSD, PSA, WHH, WHD, WHA, VCH, VCD, VCA,
       (nz(B365H, 0) + nz(BWH, 0) + nz(IWH, 0) + nz(LBH, 0) + nz(PSH, 0) + nz(WHH, 0) + nz(VCH, 0)) /
        (iif(B365H is null, 0, 1) + iif(BWH is null, 0, 1) + iif(IWH is null, 0, 1) + iif(LBH is null, 0, 1) + iif(PSH is null, 0, 1) + iif(WHH is null, 0, 1) + iif(VCH is null, 0, 1))
       )  AS AvgHome
FROM [Bund];
```